# Show title in Bootstrap-Select without empty element

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

In [Bootstrap-Select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select), how can I prevent the first selected item from being shown in the title. Alternatively, how can I hide an empty first item from the list of drop down options

In HTML, the `<select>` element will automatically select the first `<option>` element by default.  The typical way around this is to create a blank first row, but this looks pretty odd as part of the dropdown menu exposed by bootstrap select.

Here are my two options:

```html
<select class="selectpicker" title="Pick One">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>

<select class="selectpicker" title="Pick One">
  <option></option>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

But neither look very good. The first ignore the `title` property entirely and the second has a blank space which looks weird on a dropdown menu:

[image: screenshot]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" title="Pick One">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>

<select class="selectpicker" title="Pick One">
  <option></option>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Method 1 - Update Bootstrap-Select Version >1.7

Per the release notes in [Version 1.7.0](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/releases/tag/v1.7.0):

> [#888](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/888), [#738](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/738): Show "title" when using a non-multiple select
>   A blank option is prepended to the select, which is then selected by
>   default. This allows the title to be shown when the select is initially
>   loaded and "no" options are selected yet.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.0/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.0/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
```

**Demo with Stack Snippets**:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.0/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.0/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" >
  <option data-hidden="true">Pick One</option>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

### Method 2 - Hide empty option with CSS

You can hide the first `<li>` element in the dropdown menu like this (although you'd probably want to base it off a class so it didn't happen by default).

```css
.bootstrap-select ul.dropdown-menu li:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

**Demo with Stack Snippets**:

```css
.bootstrap-select ul.dropdown-menu li:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.0/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.0/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" title="Pick One" >
  <option></option>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

### Method 3 - Hide empty option with data attributes

As suggested by @Antiga, you can hide the first option with `data-hidden="true"` like this:

```html
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option data-hidden="true">Pick One</option>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

**Demo with Stack Snippets**:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.0/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.0/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" >
  <option data-hidden="true">Pick One</option>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does `<option data-hidden="true">Pick One</option>` work? (Without any of the CSS?)

Comment: @Antiga, great idea!  This is much cleaner! In my particular case I'm generating the HTML with MVC which doesn't take too kindly to adding attributes to SelectListItem's, but that's a problem for a different question.

Comment: I prefer method 2

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to set it to be a **multiple select** dropdown, but limit the number of **selected items to 1**.

```html
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-max-options="1" title="Pick One">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-max-options="1" title="Pick One">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

A JS version:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeName == "DIV") {
        $(this).find('ul.dropdown-menu li:first').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the attribute title from the select element and make sure the first option is empty:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="selectpicker form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

(If you want to take full advantage of bootstrap, consider add the extra elements and classes present in my example).

Comment: I like the idea of going native bootstrap, but this doesn't look like it meets the criteria of "`how can I hide an empty first item from the list of drop down options`" ([example](http://i.imgur.com/NhposoR.png))

Comment: Ups! That's right. This code hides the title only. It seems I completly miss read the topic.